# What does kb show for 64 bit processes?

Tags: debugging, 64-bit, windbg, stack-trace

I have recently made a mistake analyzing a callstack, because I didn't expect the application to be 64 bit. I have used the WinDbg command `kb` to show the callstack and parameters passed to methods.

On 64 bit, the parameters are not passed via the stack but in registers (RCX, RDX, R8 and R9) instead. It seems that WinDbg has not or not fully implemented this. Partly I guess it is almost impossible since the register values might have changed meanwhile.

However, the WinDbg help still lists `kb` as a valid command under `User-Mode, x64 Processor`. Therefore my question is:

What does `kb` display for 64 bit user mode processes? When/how is that output useful?

Comment: Stack walks cannot show you accurate function argument values.  Passed in registers, they were spilled to memory before the register was used to store something else.  Very painful if you really need to know, digging out the memory address is *not* simple.  Last time I looked, been a while, it was something I had to learn how to live with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Args to Child" output shown in kb and kv in WinDbg has always been very suspect, even on the x86 those columns don't necessarily show you the arguments to the function.

On the x86, the "Args to Child" are simply [EBP+0x08], [EBP+0x0C], and [EBP+0x10] (kv shows four arguments, thus the last column is [EBP+0x14]). These will only be the arguments to the function if:

1. The function uses an EBP frame
2. The function has stack passed arguments (depends on the calling convention)
3. The optimizer hasn't reused those locations for something else

On the x64, as you noted the first four arguments to the function are passed via registers. However, as part of the calling convention the caller is required to allocate "Home" (or "Spill") Space on the stack for each of these arguments. This space is **always** allocated, even if the called function takes fewer than four arguments. The called function is then free to use this Home Space any way it chooses, it may:

1. Ignore it
2. Save non-volatile registers there
3. "Home" the register passed parameters onto the stack

The kb and kv output shows the Home Space in order (RCX Home, RDX Home, R8 Home, R9 Home). Most frequently this space will be used for 1 or 2 above, thus it won't actually have anything to do with the passed in arguments. However, in the Debug build the compiler immediately Homes the passed in arguments to make debugging easier.

For example, here's the prolog of a function with two arguments compiled Debug. Note the Homing of the arguments as the first instructions:

```
0:000> u DriverEntry
mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx
mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
push    rdi
sub     rsp,0C0h
```

And the same code compiled Release, using the Home Space for non-volatile register preservation:

```
0:000> u DriverEntry
mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdi
push    rbp
lea     rbp,[rsp-57h]
sub     rsp,0B0h
```

This means the Home Space is usually pretty useless in terms of getting the arguments to the function. However, it can still be used as a debugging aid to reconstruct non-volatile register values on function entry (i.e. I can tell you the value of RBX or RDI above by looking at the Home Space)

Answer (score 4):

kb does list the stack back trace along with the three parameters, however it's the parameter passing mechanism (calling convention) which doesn't make the arguments displayed trustworthy. You must read more @ http://www.codemachine.com/article_x64deepdive.html

dv , and all other variants dv /v etc may all show garbage values. only in case of __this call we can use rcx as a this pointer but we must disassemble and ensure the pointer was not backed up somewhere else and then reused. Dis-assembly is the way to go unless we have homed parameters.