# Dump out all Args to Child on a given stack

Tags: windbg

How do I dump out all Args to Child for my current thread stack e.g.  I want to do a command like `du` on the args for every frame in the current stack. Like `du ebp+<1st 4 args>` on all frames.

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `kP`? this will show all params for each call in a stack trace on a separate line

Comment: `kP`and `kb` may not work well on x64 due to changed calling conventions

Comment: Maybe `!for_each_frame` is part of the solution.

Comment: yes thats why i submitted the question the syntax is mind blowing

Comment: Args to Child is poorly named, it's not even necessarily the arguments to the function on the x86. See my answer here for what these columns mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740674/what-does-kb-show-for-64-bit-processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it's not very easy to do in WinDbg itself, but I can recommend [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) to solve this task. Make sure you have Python installed in the correct bitness (same bitness as WinDbg that you want to use).

```
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .reload
0:000> .load E:\...\pykd\0.3.0.27\x86\pykd.dll
```

Use `pykd.pyd` if there's no `pykd.dll`.

```
0:000> !py
>>> s = getStack()
>>> for f in s:
...     for p in range(1,4):
...         print("%016X" % (ptrPtr(f.sp + p*ptrSize())))
... 
>>> exit()
```

- `s` is the stack of the current thread.
- `for f in s` loops over all frames.
- `p` will be the parameters where `0` would be the return address and `1` to `4` are the parameters as displayed by `kb`.
- `p*ptrSize()` calculates the correct offset with respect to the bitness
- `f.sp` gives you the stack pointer of the current frame
- `ptrPtr()` reads pointer-sized (bitness aware) data from memory
- `"%016X" % n` formats the number in hex
- `exit()` gets you out of the interactive console

Now that you have all the parameters, you can also dump their values as strings. You can try `loadWStr()` of PyKd. Here's a complete script:

```
from pykd import *
s = getStack()
for f in s:
    for p in range(1,4):
        paramaddr = f.sp + p*ptrSize()
        string = loadWStr(paramaddr)
        print(string)
```

If you want to apply it to all threads, run it like this:

```
0:000> ~*e !py string.py
```